# Ruby: How to import a variable from another file?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a local config file to use with compass so we can cope with differing import paths on developers' machines. So far I've tried to import the file inside an exception block, incase it doesn't exist, then use the variable further down:

**local_config.rb**

```
VENV_FOLDER = 'venv'
```

**config.rb**

```
VENV_FOLDER = '.'
begin
  require 'local_config.rb'
rescue LoadError
end
puts VENV_FOLDER
```

Normally I'm a Python developer so I'd expect the import to change the value of `VENV_FOLDER` to `venv`, however it's still `.` afterwards.

Is there a way to import `local_config.rb` in such a way that it overrides the value of `VENV_FOLDER`?

Comment: Did you test if the file can be found or if there is an exception? Otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: Note that `Exception` is the big superclass of errors. It captures even `SyntaxError`, you probably don't want that. There's `LoadError`, you probably want this one.

Comment: @Howard Yes, just double checked that by taking it out of the exception block. No errors unfortunately.

Comment: @Tass Thanks, I've updated my code and the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other alternatives:

### YAML (or JSON)

**local_config.yml**

```
venv_folder: 'venv'
```

**config.rb**

```
require 'yaml'

VENV_FOLDER = begin
  YAML.load_file('local_config.yml').fetch('venv_folder')
rescue Errno::ENOENT, KeyError
  '.'
end

puts VENV_FOLDER
```

### Class instance variable

You could put the value in a class instance variable:

**local_config.rb**

```
Config.venv = 'venv'
```

**config.rb**

```
class Config
  class << self ; attr_accessor :venv ; end
  self.venv = '.'
end

begin
  require './local_config.rb'
rescue LoadError
end

puts Config.venv
```

### Constants

Also, sticking to ruby files with constants, the following is perhaps marginally clearer in its intentions and avoids having to catch exceptions.

**local_config.rb**

```
VENV_FOLDER = 'venv'
```

**config.rb**

```
config_file = './local_config.rb'
require config_file if File.file? config_file
VENV_FOLDER ||= '.'

puts VENV_FOLDER
```

All three solutions have different mechanisms for ensuring that the value will be set even if the file is missing or doesn't set the value as expected. Hope it's helpful

Comment: All these methods work under 1.9.2-p290 by calling `ruby config.rb`, but there shouldn't be any reason why they would fail on 1.8 that I can think of...

Answer (score 1):

The path to the file is wrong.  It needs to include a slash if it isn't loaded from $LOAD_PATH.

Your `LoadError` is being caught silently.

If you do this:

```
VENV_FOLDER = '.'

begin
  require './local_config.rb'
rescue LoadError
end

puts VENV_FOLDER
```

Then you'll see it works.

Better still:

```
VENV_FOLDER = '.'

require File.expand_path('../local_config.rb', __FILE__) rescue LoadError

puts VENV_FOLDER
```

Since the second version doesn't depend on the PWD of the user who invokes the script.

Constant re-assignment is a bad idea however.  Ruby will let you do it, but you'll get a warning.  I believe your confusion was just with the LoadError though.

Comment: Or better yet in 1.9: `require_relative 'local_config' rescue LoadError`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**local_config.rb**

```
VENV[:folder] = 'venv'
```

**config.rb**

```
VENV = {:folder => '.'}
begin
    load 'local_config.rb'
rescue Exception
end

puts VENV[:folder]
```

Here's working version for ruby 1.9.3: https://gist.github.com/1501237

for ruby 1.8.7: https://gist.github.com/1501321

Comment: I gave this method a go, but since `VENV` doesn't exist in local_config.rb I can't assign to it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running 1.8.7 and we can't realistically update all our machines to 1.9.3. Using your example I get the error "uninitialized constant VENV". I tried adding `require 'config.rb'` to the top of local_config.rb which stops this error but I still have the same problem with the `VENV[:folder]` being `.` not `venv`.

Comment: try using `load` instead of `require`. I don't have 1.8 right now, I would test it myself

Comment: It works on my machine with ruby-1.8.7-p334, check if you are loading local_config.rb somewhere else then in the block in config.rb file

Comment: Anyway, if you use global variables ($venv_folder='.') you can probably get what you want, but since it seems the order of loading is somewhat messed up I'm not sure it would work

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev: This is not correct. "Ruby [...] lets you alter the value of a constant, although this will generate a warning message." (http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html) Just try it in irb.

Comment: I saw the warning and thought it is an exception.