# Can two different .rb files access the same variable?

Tags: ruby

I have scripts web.rb (sinatra) and rufus.rb (cron using rufus gem) running on the same computer (Win XP). Both are using functions.rb where I have all the functions. I have an array variable $webserver_status where I store history of commands web server performed/is performing. The web server runs some dos commands and php scripts and I want to be sure that only one runs at a time and also give the user some overview what is happening.

I used to run cron jobs (rufus.rb) over http so in fact I access the web server as from the browser. So the status variable was updated correctly. Now I started to call the same code from functions.rb so the variable doesn't show correct server status any more.

**Is there any way cron can access the $webserver_status variable directly?**

Or I have to update the variable over http? Or some kind of status file on the disk?

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- web server runs at all times
- I have production and testing version of cron code

Comment: Is there any reason why a JSON http request wouldn't work?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I wanted to get rid of running the cron job over http. So I run "web code" directly from cron. But cron cannot access the web variable.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking, but I think ditching cron might solve your problems. What is the end goal?

Comment: Web server run test scripts, displays results etc. Cron runs some tasks overnight that web server provides. So far I was running 'middle man code' to run cron task over http but I wanted to get rid of this middle part.

Comment: What is "cron task over http" ?

Comment: Middle part runs "cron task" over http via web.rb. Cron task could be anything that web.rb could do but this time it will be triggered by cron not by a real person.

Comment: How can you run a cron task over HTTP? Cron isn't a client/server. It might be useful to type it out like `Computer A Calls Web.rb via SSH on Computer B. Computer B then runs rufus.rb via cron...` I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Probably I had to be clearer in my question when saying that I use rufus (ruby gem) as cron. Web.rb and rufus.rb (the cron) runs on same computer. rufus.rb (the cron) runs the tasks over http to access web.rb code. So I thought I would get rid of this http execution.

Comment: Would be nice to say why you downvoted ...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
#web.rb
require './functions'

print_value("apple")
```

and

```
#rufus.rb
require './functions'

print_value("not apple")
```

and

```
#functions.rb

def print_value(value)
  puts value
end
```

Calling web.rb returns the string Apple.

Comment: I will play around with this. In fact I need it the other way around. rufus accesses web's variables. What would happen if web is not running?

Comment: It's the general idea. If web isn't running, you would need to call it via a cron job, manually, or some other way to get it 'jump started'

Comment: What if I have all functions in my function.rb file?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I want to update a web.rb variable when calling the update code from rufus.rb. It updates different variable with the same name if the variable is defined in functions.rb.

Comment: You need some type of storage. Something like a text file would be simplest. Right?

Comment: It looks like that. I am just implementing that. I hoped I can do that without any hdd activity...

Answer (score 2):

See the suggestions I made [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574206/ruby-how-to-import-a-variable-from-another-file/8576984#8576984). The question was essentially the same unless I'm missing something in your scenario. There are many possible solutions depending on your needs.

***Edit***:

Based on your comment, I'm guessing that you want to share memory across two ruby processes or otherwise communicate between processes. Read about [IPC in ruby](http://jstorimer.com/2012/04/19/intro-to-ruby-ipc.html) to see how you could make UNIX sockets suit your needs.

It doesn't really make sense to talk about the same variable being accessed in two processes - you have to go via some kind of intermediary whether it's sockets, a database or a file. If this isn't what you want then I suggest you clarify the situation and why you need shared access to the memory rather than something like this.

Comment: I want to update the variable of web.rb while the web.rb is running.

Comment: Then keep the value in a database or YAML/JSON file and have web.rb periodically check the db/file and replace its internal variable with the value it finds there.

Comment: I am doing that but I thought/hoped that there is `only memory` solution.